# In Oracle , How to handle the following Situation using procedure?

Tags: oracle, procedure

Assume this table has following data in it.

```
123 || MYNTRA || 345 || Flipkart
123 || MYNTRA || 678 || Snapdeal

In Table 1, 123 is PARENT whose Children are 345,678. There are 'N' no. of such Children to Parent 123.

Now Assume that 123 has following 2 offers i.e Parent has 3 offers
123 || Offer1_Myntra || Description_Offer1
123 || Offer2_Myntra || Description_Offer2

Now as Children are extended from Parent, Parent's Each offer SHOULD be in Children with SAME DATA (Not Even Mismatch of single space)
i.e 

345 || Offer1_Myntra || Description_Offer1
678 || Offer2_Myntra || Description_Offer2

Also Order of occurrence of offers in Children may vary like as : ()

678 || Offer2_Myntra || Description_Offer2
345 || Offer1_Myntra || Description_Offer1
```

I want to compare these situations using cursor & for loop.
I want to find out MISMATCH between this data & display columns having MISMATCH. 
Can You Help with logic & Code ?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest some way, only with sql queries like below

first i will name the columns.
Table1 with columns

```
parent_1
site_1
child_1
site_2
```

table2 with columns like below

```
parent_1 
offer_1
off_desc_1
```

Now the code will be

```
create table tmp_tab(parent_1 varchar2(50),child_1 varchar2(50),offer_1 varchar2(50),off_desc_1 varchar2(50));

Insert into tmp_tab
select a.parent_1,a.child_1,b.offer_1,b.off_desc_1 
from table1 a
join 
table2 b
on a.parent_1 = b.paren_1
```

which will give the cross join between the `parent_1` hence result will be

```
select * from tmp_tab;

123||345 || Offer1_Myntra || Description_Offer1
123||678 || Offer2_Myntra || Description_Offer2
123||678 || Offer2_Myntra || Description_Offer2
123||345 || Offer1_Myntra || Description_Offer1
```

from the above we can easily eliminate the duplicate like below

```
delete from 
   tmp_tab a
where 
   a.rowid > 
   any (select b.rowid
   from 
      tmp_tab b
   where 
      a.parent_1 = b.parent_1
   and 
      a.child_1 = b.child_1
   )
;
```

which will give you expected result